# How to change the order or sequence of land types in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am trying to use the raster calculator to compute the landuse land change and to that the raster sequence has the to be the same but what it looks like currently is the following:

These maps are raster and I'm trying to make them have the same order or squence of types, I tried to use the reclassify tool but it didn't work

Map 2007

| RowID | Value | Count | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 34 | Magrove |
| 1 | 2 | 54 | Muflat |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | Water |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | Built |
| 4 | 5 | 50 | reeds |

Map 2018

| RowID | Value | Count | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 45 | Water |
| 1 | 2 | 20 | Reed |
| 2 | 3 | 87 | Mudflat |
| 3 | 4 | 23 | Built |
| 4 | 5 | 80 | Mnagrove |

The problem is that the 2018 map does not follow the type or value of the 2007 and for the raster calculator to compute the Land use land change the type has to be arranged the same way as the one in 2007. because I have to make a matrix like this

|  | Water | Reed | Mudflat | Built | Mangrove |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Water |  | 0 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| Reed |  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| Mudflat |  | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| Built |  | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| Mangrove |  | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |

My expected outcome for the 2018 map raster is to that the type and sequence is similar to that of 2007:

Map 2007

| RowID | Value | Count | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 34 | Magrove |
| 1 | 2 | 54 | Muflat |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | Water |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | Built |
| 4 | 5 | 50 | reeds |

Map 2018

| RowID | Value | Count | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 80 | Magrove |
| 1 | 2 | 87 | Muflat |
| 2 | 3 | 45 | Water |
| 3 | 4 | 23 | Built |
| 4 | 5 | 20 | reeds |

Comment: Just Combine 2 rasters and do pivot table in Excel using raster A for rows, B for columns,  count sum. You always can match row - column names to their descriptions

Comment: But can't I edit it in ArcGIS or if I export it to excel and put it back with my raster map is it possible? Thank you

Comment: Is matrix you objective or something else?

Comment: My object is to change the other of the TYPE in the attribute table. How cna I do that